# How logical/boolean operators work in an if else if statement?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I'm building a tic tac toe game and I'm trying to use an if else if statement for my win conditions. I've tried a couple different methods for My conditions.
Here's all my coding for it:

```js
var Box1=document.getElementById("box1"); //getting the grid spots and putting them into variables
var Box2=document.getElementById("box2");
var Box3=document.getElementById("box3");
var Box4=document.getElementById("box4");
var Box5=document.getElementById("box5");
var Box6=document.getElementById("box6");
var Box7=document.getElementById("box7");
var Box8=document.getElementById("box8");
var Box9=document.getElementById("box9");
var a1=document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML; //getting the innerHTML of the grid spots to check for x or o later
var a2=document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML;
var a3=document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML;
var a4=document.getElementById("box4").innerHTML;
var a5=document.getElementById("box5").innerHTML;
var a6=document.getElementById("box6").innerHTML;
var a7=document.getElementById("box7").innerHTML;
var a8=document.getElementById("box8").innerHTML;
var a9=document.getElementById("box9").innerHTML;
var playerchar="x"; //setting the first player as x

Box1.addEventListener("click", box1); //adding click event for when grid spot 1, 1 is clicked
function box1() {
 Box1.innerHTML=playerchar; //Setting the innerHTML of the clicked grid spot 
 Box1.removeEventListener("click", box1);// removing click event
 checkwin(); // check for a win condition
 if(playerchar=="x") { // 
  playerchar="o"; //if the last turn was an x then change it to o.
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x"; //if the last turn was o then change it to x.
 }
}

Box2.addEventListener("click", box2);
function box2() {
 Box2.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box2.removeEventListener("click", box2);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
 
}

Box3.addEventListener("click", box3);
function box3() {
 Box3.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box3.removeEventListener("click", box3);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box4.addEventListener("click", box4);
function box4() {
 Box4.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box4.removeEventListener("click", box4);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box5.addEventListener("click", box5);
function box5() {
 Box5.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box5.removeEventListener("click", box5);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box6.addEventListener("click", box6);
function box6() {
 Box6.innerHTML=playerchar;
 checkwin();
 Box6.removeEventListener("click", box6)
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box7.addEventListener("click", box7);
function box7() {
 Box7.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box7.removeEventListener("click", box7);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box8.addEventListener("click", box8);
function box8() {
 Box8.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box8.removeEventListener("click", box8);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}

Box9.addEventListener("click", box9);
function box9() {
 Box9.innerHTML=playerchar;
 Box9.removeEventListener("click", box9);
 checkwin();
 if(playerchar=="x") {
  playerchar="o";
 }
 else if(playerchar=="o") {
  playerchar="x";
 }
}
function checkwin() {
 if(a1==a2 && a1==a3 && a1=="x" || a1=="o") { //check for win with top row
  quit(); //function for what happens when someone wins
 }
 else if(a4==a5 && a4==a6 && a4=="x" || a4=="o") { // check for win with second row
  quit();
 }
 else if(a7==a8 && a7==a9 && a7=="x" || a7=="o") { //check for win with third row
  quit();
 }
 else if(a1==a4 && a1==a7 && a1=="x" || a1=="o") {// check for win with first column
  quit();
 }
 else if(a2==a5 && a2==a8 && a2=="x" || a2=="o") {//check for win with second column
  quit();
 }
 else if(a3==a6 && a3==a9 && a3=="x" || a3=="o") { // check for win with third column
  quit();
 }
 else if((a1 == 'x' || a1 == 'o') && a1==a5 || a1==a9) { //check for win from top left to bottom right
      quit();
 }
 else if((a3==a5 && a3==a7) && (a3=="x" || a3=="o")) { // check for win from top right to bottom left
  quit();
 }
}
function quit() {
 alert("Someone won");
}
```

```css
#container {
 cell-spacing: 0px;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 margin: 30px ;
 border-collapse: separate;
}
table tr td {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 font-size: 35px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#container tr:first-child td
    border-top: none
}

#container tr:last-child td
    border-bottom: none
}

#container tr td:first-child
    border-left: none;
}

#container tr td:last-child
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
 <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2> Player 1 is x</h2>
 <h2>Player 2 is o</h2>
 <div id="container">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="box1"></td>
    <td id="box2"></td>
    <td id="box3"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="box4"></td>
    <td id="box5"></td>
    <td id="box6"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="box7"></td>
    <td id="box8"></td>
    <td id="box9"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TicTacToe.js"></script>
</html>
```

So when a player clicks on one of the td's that haven't been clicked yet, it takes the player character and puts it into the innerHTML of the td. Then changes the player character to the opposing value. How can I make the checkwin() function check all 8 possible win conditions for x or o.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might need  provide more context. Are `a1`, `a2`, ... representing the fields? If so, which ones? What excactly do you want to check for?

Comment: A1-9 are my fields innerHTML's.  A1 is the top left spot of the board, a9 is the bottom right. I'm trying to check if there are 3 in a row with the same innerHTML, with the condition of them also equally "o" or "x" which is what I used for when someone clicks on one of the spots to the game.

Comment: Then you _could_ do it as you wrote (or rather, as suggested in the answer by @Nicholas Smith). But as there are 8 possible three-in-a-row combinations, it would be quite a long if-statement. You might find it much cleaner (and maybe, more insightful) to put the innerHTMLs in a two-dimensional array (instead of single variables) and use `for`-loops iterating over it to check for the combinations. (That would also make the code more flexible, for example if you want to expand the game to a larger grid than 3x3.)

Comment: Would this fix my checkwin() function? I posted the whole code so people can have better insight of what I'm asking for. It doesn't seem to show any winning combinations, and I'm not sure on how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. My a1-a9 variables were getting innerHTML before being clicked on, so all my win condition variables were null. Just had to move the variables to the checkwin() function to refresh them.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to test if `A1`, `A5`, and `A9` all contain the same character (either "x" or "o") and quit.  Otherwise, if `A3`, `A5`, and `A7` all contain the same character (either "x" or "o") then quit?  Something like your posted code should work fine.

```
else if((a1 == 'x' || a1 == 'o') && a1==a5 && a1==a9) {
    quit();
}
else if((a3 == 'x' || a3 == 'o') && a3==a5 && a3==a7) {
    quit();
}
```

Comment: I think the other checks are performed to see, whether the fields are actually taken. If so, you're missing that, and even an empty field will trigger `quit()`.

Comment: Those are just a couple of the win condition checks, I can post more code if need be, the javascript is 170 lines of coding though not sure if it'd all be relevant. And yes I am trying to check if all 3 contain the same character.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did first sirko, and every board spot triggered my quit() function.

Comment: Sorry I realized that after I posted, I've edited the answer.

Comment: I edited my post with all of the code. I tried the way that you wrote it, and still my checkwin() function doesn't initiate the quit() function when I have x or o in the 3 spots for that specific condition.